# .Net 7 An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)

Tags: c#, .net

I got no idea what this error is about in Net 7. Suddenly the project become not able to start in console or in IIS Express.

> An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709654/cannot-open-log-for-source-net-runtime-you-may-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, the issue is because Windows Services "Windows Event Log" is not Start.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same error message (IIS on production server) and the "Windows Event Log" was not running (and could not be started for some reason). To finally resolve, I switched the AppPool from "No Managed Code" to ".NET CLR Version v4.0.30319". I tried hitting the web site and it was now working! However, since it is a .NET Core app, I then switched the AppPool back to "No Managed Code". It continued working fine.

Seems like switching to .NET CLR did something to add some missing bits (maybe registry entries??) which then prevented further errors.

Posting this in case it helps someone else as it took a bit of fiddling to figure this out.